# Trying to use XSLT 2.0 to embed CSS that contains '>' child selector in HTML <style> element

Tags: html, css, xslt

My file base.css contains:

```
ol > li { color: red; }
```

I try to read it and render it into my HTML output using XSLT 2.0 unparsed-text (Saxon 9.1.0.2J) like this :

```
<style>
  <xsl:sequence select="unparsed-text(fn:iri-to-uri($CSS-BASE-FILE))"/>
</style>
```

However, the unparsed-text() function is converting the '>' to '&gt;' in the HTML, like this:

```
<style>
ol &gt; li { color: red; }
</style>
```

...Which doesn't behave as "ol > li" does.

How can I use XSLT to render the '>' character into my  element? I've tried using replace(..., '&gt;', '>'), but that still renders '&gt;' into the HTML.

Alternatively, is there another way I can specify the CSS child selector without having to embed a literal '>' character into my HTML?

Comment: I think the problem is `xsl:sequence`. Why do you want to render the value of the unparsed text as a sequence instead of a literal string?

Comment: Using `xxl:value` yields the same result. Ah, but your comment leads me to the doorstep of `disable-output-escaping`, documented at [saxonica.com](http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/xsl-elements/value-of.html).

Comment: The magic I needed is `<xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text(fn:iri-to-uri($CSS-BASE-FILE))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using output method XML, XHTML, or HTML?

The (3.0) specification says this:

The HTML output method MUST NOT perform escaping for any text node descendant, nor for any attribute of an element node descendant, of a script or style element.

So my suspicion is that you are not using the HTML output method.

Comment: Hi, Mike. I'm using method="xhtml".

Comment: That explains it then. The XHTML output method generally follows the XML rules except for a few special situations where it does things differently. Generally I'm not sure there's much point generating XHTML for the browser: it understands HTML better, and if you have a need for an XML representation then you can generate that alongside the HTML.

Comment: So, Mike, to be clear on what you're saying: if I use <xsl:output method='html'>, then I won't need to use the disable-output-escaping attribute on the <xsl:value of> element (which does seem to work fine for me). Is that correct? Thank you.

Comment: I checked the W3C 3.0 spec, I didn't check the Saxon 9.1 implementation, but in principle yes, with method="html" it should work.